How to concatenate three dataframes with the same indexes and columns in Pandas
I want to concatenate three dataframes with the same indexes and column names to obtain the final table with keeping indexes and columns where values for the particular indexes are presented row by row (some multiindexing is needed I guess). I've tried to do it with:
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'P1-6': [53, 141, 51], 'P1-12': [64, 127, 56], 'P1-22': [57, 140, 56]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1, index=['hAT|1', 'hAT|2', 'hAT|3'])

d2 = {'P1-6': [9, 21, 80], 'P1-12': [14, 36, 70], 'P1-22': [16, 31, 68]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2, index=['hAT|1', 'hAT|2', 'hAT|3'])

d_sum = {'P1-6': [62, 162, 131], 'P1-12': [78, 163, 126], 'P1-22': [73, 171, 124]}
df_sum = pd.DataFrame(data=d_sum, index=['hAT|1', 'hAT|2', 'hAT|3'])

final_table = pd.concat([df1, df2, df_sum], keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df_sum'])

but the effect looks like this:
              P1-6  P1-12  P1-22
df1    hAT|1    53     64     57
       hAT|2   141    127    140
       hAT|3    51     56     56
df2    hAT|1     9     14     16
       hAT|2    21     36     31
       hAT|3    80     70     68
df_sum hAT|1    62     78     73
       hAT|2   162    163    171
       hAT|3   131    126    124


and desired result should be:
              P1-6  P1-12  P1-22
hAT|1    df1    53     64     57
         df2     9     14     16
      df_sum    62     78     73
hAT|2    df1   141    127    140
         df2    21     36     31
      df_sum   162    163    171
hAT|3    df1    51     56     56
         df2    80     70     68
      df_sum   131    126    124

Is it possible to do it?

You can swaplevel and sort_index:
final_table = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df_sum], keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df_sum'])
                 .swaplevel().sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False)
              )

Or reindex:
final_table = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df_sum], keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df_sum'])
                 .swaplevel().reindex(df_sum.index, level=0)
              )

Output:
              P1-6  P1-12  P1-22
hAT|1 df1       53     64     57
      df2       53     64     57
      df_sum    62     78     73
hAT|2 df1      141    127    140
      df2      141    127    140
      df_sum   162    163    171
hAT|3 df1       51     56     56
      df2       51     56     56
      df_sum   131    126    124


Not sure about a standard function to achieve this, however I am able to get this using following logic...
final_table = pd.concat([df1, df2, df_sum], keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df_sum'],axis=0)
indx = final_table.index
tup = list((i[1],i[0]) for i in indx)
indx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tup)
final_table.set_index(indx,inplace=True)
final_table.sort_index(inplace=True)
final_table

OUTPUT:
               P1-6  P1-12  P1-22
   hAT|1    df1 53   64     57
            df2 53   64     57
         df_sum 62   78     73
   hAT|2    df1 141  127    140
            df2 141  127    140
         df_sum 162  163    171
   hAT|3    df1 51   56     56
            df2 51   56     56
         df_sum 131  126    124
                

